# How to run EasyModeller (GUI for Modeller) on Ubuntu 14 x64?

Tags: software-installation, python, perl, tcl

I have successfully installed Modeller.  I want to try to use the front end GUI software EasyModeller.  However, when I try to run it I receive the error message as follows:

```
user@pc:~/Downloads/EasyModeller 4.0_LINUX$ ./EasyModeller4 

Can't load 'auto/Tk/Tk.so' for module Tk: auto/Tk/Tk.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /</home/user/Downloads/EasyModeller 4.0_LINUX/EasyModeller4>DynaLoader.pm line 217.
 at perlapp line 825
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at em4.pl line 1.

user@pc:~/Downloads/EasyModeller 4.0_LINUX$
```

How can I resolve this problem?  Python, Perl, Tcl, and Tk are all installed as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

EasyModeller4 currently supports 32 bit Linux only . As your current Ubuntu is 64 bit, it is creating a problem. An alternate way out is to install the relevant 32 bit libraries in your current installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please provide a little more information?  Perhaps a step by step guide on how to install the 32bit libraries, and maybe a link to reference material? This will help other people in the future as well :)